# Fallback value for DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My application loads all strings from resource dictionaries defined in separate `XAML` files. It is possible that the `DynamicResource` key will not exist during run-time.

```
<CheckBox Content="{DynamicResource myKeyThatIsMissing}"/>
```

In a normal binding there is a Fallback value that can be used like this:

```
Text="{Binding StringToShow, FallbackValue=DefaultValue}
```

Is it possible to have a default Fallback value for a property set with a `DynamicResource` that is used if the resource key does not exist?

Comment: Try applying a style and specifying default values with property setters.

Comment: Could you give an example of this? I'm not sure how to set the default values in a setter.

Comment: http://rhyous.github.io/WPFSharp.Globalizer/ That should do what you want. But it creates a new extension to do it (DynamicResouce itself is also an extension btw).

Answer (score 1):

The class `System.Windows.DynamicResourceExtension` is unsealed so perhaps you can extend it and add the logic you desire by overriding the `ProvideValue` method.

Unfortunately the default implementation returns an instance of the internal `ResourceReferenceExpression` class, so you may have to do some reflection or other magic to make this work.